# how to rename or delete file in local storage using flutter

Tags: flutter, delete-file, file-rename, audio-player

I am developing an audio player using flutter.

In this project, I am using [on_audio_query package](https://pub.dev/packages/on_audio_query) to list all audio files from my mobile, then select one to play it.

I want to know, **is there anyway to rename a file or delete it?**

So the user can select one file and rename it, or select one or multiple files and delete them.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this example:

```
Future  changeFileNameOnly(File file, String newFileName) {
  var path = file.path;
  var lastSeparator = path.lastIndexOf(Platform.pathSeparator);
  var newPath = path.substring(0, lastSeparator + 1) + newFileName;
  return file.rename(newPath);
}
```

Comment: I am using on audio query package and it provide audio files but in another data type not file

Answer (score 0):

Use [permission_handler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler) to get access to manage_external_storage before..
Don't forget to add it in manifest

You can also use the shared storage to get access..
By using i think [saf package](https://pub.dev/packages/saf)